# What is the German equivalent to the phrase “(to) burn your straw man”?

Tags: word-choice, phrase

I am referring to the *straw man* as defined by [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Straw_man)

The part I’m having trouble with is the word(s) *straw man* as used in this context.

Does a direct translation mean the same in German? 
Is there another word(s) that mean what I am trying to convey?

*This post was edited due to the confusion over the use of *strawman* over the correct *straw man*. Apparently meaning very different things in English and implying completely different meanings when translated to German.*

Comment: Is "strawman" really the appropriate term in English? Looking at Oxford and M-W Dictionaries, I could find two definitions. One which goes along with the German "Strohmann" and one which corresponds to the German "Strohmann Argument". However, the explanation you give in the body of your question is not covered by that term. I would call it hermit or recluse. In that case, "Einsiedler" as suggested in an answer, is the right word to go with.

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, it’s not asking for a German translation of _hermit_ (i.e. _Einsiedler, Eremit, Klausner, Aussteiger, Eigenbrötler_), but for a figurative phrase that means ‘becoming a hermit’. JFTR: I’ve never encountered _strawman_ in this context either, but as described it actually makes sense. In German, more common metaphors for that concept are _Maske(rade)_ and _Fassade_ which can be _fallenlassen_ instead of being burned, maybe also _Attrappe_, _Trugbild_, _Schein-Ich_ and _Identität_.

Comment: Please edit the title of your posting, to clarify that you're looking for a translation of the expression "burn your strawman" rather than of just the word "strawman".

Comment: @Em1: Bitte "Strohmannargument", nicht "Strohmann Argument". Aber darum geht es offensichtlich nicht.

Comment: I've never heard the phrase "burn your strawman" in English and, as @Em1 says, it seems to be at odds with the usual definition of "strawman". Since "burn your strawman" has fewer than 1500 Google hits, I'd suggest using a more widely understood phrase, whether speaking English or German. Without a lot of context, I'd assume that "burn your strawman" means "quit using your strawman argument".

Comment: I have heard "auf Tauchstation gehen" being used to describe precisely this. But it is not a universally understood idiom. Regional at best.

Comment: I'm very sorry, I put the words together to form a word that really should have been two. I've caused much confusion... Here is the wikipedia article on the topic at hand.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Straw_man  I am going to delete this thread in a moment and repost.

Comment: I have never in my life heard the phrase in English as expressed in this question originally and the linked wiki article referenced in the comments talks about a straw man of arguments, nothing to do with going off into the wild and leaving things behind. I think you need to figure out what the English is that you want to express first and ask a new question. Are we now talking about straw man arguments? What does your English phrase mean in English?

Answer (score 6):

If you have a look in a dictionary, you will see that we have the literal translation of it, a [**Strohmann**](http://dict.leo.org/dictQuery/m-vocab/ende/de.html?searchLoc=0&lp=ende&lang=de&search=strohmann&resultOrder=basic), which can be used as someone who acts for somebody else; for details see [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strohmann).

However you cannot use **einen Strohmann verbrennen**, at least not differently than in the literal sense of igniting a straw puppet.
You could use **sein (bürgerliches, spießiges, langweiliges) Leben aufgeben**, **ein Aussteiger sein** oder **(aus der Gesellschaft) aussteigen** which implies your “off the grid” meaning (see [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aussteiger)).

I don’t know any phrase that is as figurative as **to burn your straw man**.

**To reflect your edit and clarification:**

If you follow this link to [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strohmann-Argument) you will see the literal translation to **Strohmann Argument** (you can also go to the English aritcle and click on "Deutsch in the left column).

Comment: _Aussteigen_ is a good term.

Comment: "die Platte machen"/"schieben" are also used for living off the street/off the land.

Comment: I'm very sorry, I put the words together to form a word that really should have been two. I've caused much confusion... Here is the wikipedia article on the topic at hand. en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Straw_man

Comment: added a paragraph about the translation to German

Answer (score 4):

The word you are looking for is **"Einsiedler"**. An "Einsielder" is someone who breaks all ties with the past (**"alle Zelte abbrechen"**) and lives alone in harmony with the nature.

Another term to describe that you are disconnecting from society is **"aussteigen"** (like @chirlu mentioned). But this term has multiple meanings and could also imply that you just break up with your old life (resign from your job, sell your household...), travel to a different part of the world (e.g. someplace where it's always warm) and start anew (e.g. search a new job, start a resturant...).

Comment: I'm very sorry, I put the words together to form a word that really should have been two. I've caused much confusion... Here is the wikipedia article on the topic at hand. en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Straw_man